# When are these two groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ be positive integers such that $mn = pq$, gcd($m,n$) $\ne 1$, gcd($p,q$) $\ne 1$, and lcm($m,n$) $=$ lcm($p,q$). Then under what condition(s) can the groups $Z_m \times Z_n$ and $Z_p \times Z_q$ (be proved to) be isomorphic? And what possible isomorphisms can we define?

What is the situation if lcm($m,n$) $\ne$ lcm($p,q$)?

Comment: An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism.

Comment: Well, under the conditions you mention, those groups are indeed isomorphic, both being isomorphic to $Z_d\times Z_k$ where $d$ is the gcd and $k$ is the lcm of the numbers.

Comment: And similarly, it can be checked that if the lcm's are not equal, then the products are not isomorphic (by considering a prime dividing the gcd's a different number of times and noting that this gives a subgroup in one of a form not found in the other)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all what you need here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group

Try to express both sides in either the primary decomposition or in the invariant factor decomposition. These decompositions are unique.